# searching in populated GridView using Select statements

Tags: asp.net, oledb

I have a gridview on my webpage that binds from an excel sheet using OleDb

Now I'm trying to set it up so that people can search just by typing a word in the textbox, and then after button click, it'd filter all the results that have the same word in any column

I was advised to use this code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search = TextBox1.Text;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;            
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);            
        grvCarProof.DataSource = dt.Select("CP number = ");
        grvCarProof.DataBind();

    }
```

what I can't figure out is what kind of writing should go in my SelectCommand(). Am i on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataView` and its `RowFilter` property.

```
DataView dv=dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter="[Cp Number]='value']";
grvCarProof.DataSource = dv;
grvCarProof.DataBind();
```

Or add WHERE clause,

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] where [column1]=@col1", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1",inputValueFromUser);
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
 da.SelectCommand = cmd;            
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);            
 grvCarProof.DataSource = dt;
 grvCarProof.DataBind();
```